# R CMD INSTALL unrecognized character

Tags: r, windows, package, special-characters

I am developping a package on windows and the path to my package contains a special character (é for instance).

This character is not recognized and is replaced by `i` in the path to the DESCRIPTION file, thus not found:

```
PS C:\Users\Clément\dev\main\myPackage> C:\'Program Files'\R\R-3.4.0\bin\x64\Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source C:\Users\"Clément"\dev\main\myPackage
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Clément/Documents/R/win-library/3.4'
* installing *source* package 'myPackage' ...
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Climent/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/myPackage/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'myPackage'
* removing 'C:/Users/Clément/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/myPackage'
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: In my opinion there is a problem with the word `Clément` in your path. In the warning message you can see `Climent` instead of `Clément`... Could you try to install the package in a different directory ?

Comment: it's a package I am developping and so all the sources are in this directory.